# PowerShell processing of large CSV very slow - Is there a better way?

Tags: powershell, csv, import

Using Powershell and am working through a `foreach` loop. One of the steps inside the loop is to find a match in a csv file -

```
import-csv ".\RateCard.csv" | where-object{$($Item.'From Number') -match "^\+?($($_.Destination))\w*$"}
```

The foreach loop is processing around 100,000 records for a month time period and completes within a few minutes without the csv lookup. After adding the csv lookup I can see its taking about 5-10 seconds for each lookup. The csv file has 40,000 rows and about 10 columns.

While I understand that client side processing is going to be slower, and that I should probably look at using SQL, I wondered if there is a faster way to do this. I thought of using a stream reader but couldn't work out how I could do a match lookup.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be the entire CSV is being scanned for each iteration.  I'm not at all fluent with PowerShell, but I know you can incorporate any .NET assembly.  An approach that loads the lookup into a Dictionary and looks up against the Dictionary would probably perform orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: You definitely need to get that import-csv outside of the loop.  You should only do that once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mjolinor suggested, move your Import-CSV outside the ForEach loop:

```
$RateCard = importcsv ".\ratecard.csv"
ForEach($Item in $Items){
    if($RateCard.Destination -contains $Item.'From Number'){
        Do Stuff
    }
}
```

I just added a If/Then function to check if your Item's From Number is found in the CSV's Destination field.